# Can my landlord prohibit me from having visitors with dogs?

Tags: california, residential-lease, pets

My apartment manager has suddenly told us that we can't have friends with dogs visiting (not overnight visits, just for an hour or two).  Is this legal?

This is in California, USA. There's nothing about animals in the lease. We've only had friends with a dog visit twice in the last couple of years, and there were no dog damage/noise/anything problems, so I'm not sure where this is coming from other than the manager just having a general issue with dogs.

Comment: Curious if you mentioned the lack of anything in the lease to the manger and what the reaction was.

Comment: @Scott  We haven't yet - we've had difficulties communicating with the manager lately, so I'm trying to do research in advance in order to keep the eventual conversation to a minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subject to the provisions of the lease and the law, a tenant is entitled to "quiet enjoyment" of the premises which basically means that the landlord can't tell you what to do with your leasehold and can't bother you while you enjoy it.

If the lease is silent about animals then the only thing preventing you having a menagerie are the laws where you live (local, state & national) - these probably do have rules about dogs (and menageries) but probably don't prohibit them.

On the other hand; who needs the grief. Tell the landlord you will ask your dog owning friends not to bring them when they visit but if someone turns up with a dog notwithstanding you won't be turning them away.

Comment: Good to know! And yeah, that's pretty much the plan.